# pageTitle in sharepoint 2013 ms-core-pageTitle

Tags: page-layout, custom-masterpage

I want to hide page title in my home page of share point 2013 (Only in home page because I want it in my for example lists and ...) how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your homepage is `Home.aspx` you could add some simple CSS like the below to your masterpage or page layout.

```
<style>
#aspnetForm[action*="Home.aspx"] .ms-core-pageTitle
{
    display: none;
}
</style>
```